# Alpine.js When I re-render with x-for, the checked of checkbox is removed

Tags: alpine.js

```
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

    <style>
        input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <div x-data="taggle()" class="" style="height: 500px;margin:30px;">
        <input x-model="text" type="text" id="tag" list="taglist" placeholder="Enter a tag" style="width:15em;">
        <button id="addTag" @click="addTag()">addTag</button>
        <div id="div_tags"></div>

        <datalist id="taglist">
            <option value="html"></option>
            <option value="PHP"></option>
            <option value="JavaScript"></option>
            <option value="CSS"></option>
        </datalist>
        <template x-for="(tag,index) in tags" :key="index">
            <label style="margin: 0px 10px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" :id="tag.id" :value="tag.text" :checked="tag.isChecke"
                    @change="removeTag($event,index)">
                <span x-text="tag.text"></span>
            </label>
        </template>
    </div>
    <script>
        const taggle = () => ({
            text: '',
            tags: [],
            addTag() {
                if (this.text.trim() == '') return;
                this.tags.push(this.newTag());
            },
            newTag() {
                tag = {
                    id: badId(),
                    text: this.text,
                    isChecke:true,
                };
                this.text = '';
                return tag;
            },
            removeTag($event,index) {
              console.log($event.target.checked);
                this.tags.splice(index, 1);
            },
        });
        function badId() {
            return (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(0);
        }
    </script>
```

https://codepen.io/y0sh1m0t0/pen/eYeyJod

1. added tag
2. Removed first tag. For some reason, the second checkbox is unchecked.
3. The checkbox in the code are checked, but they do not work.
4. If you remove the checkmark from behind, no problem will occur.

[It would be helpful if you could see the images for more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWNL2.png)

The cause of this is unknown.
I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code as follows, and it worked.

```
//correction
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" :id="tag.id" :value="tag.text" checked
     @change="removeTag($event,tag)">


//correction
removeTag($event,tag) {
   // console.log($event.target.id,tag.id);
   this.tags = this.tags.filter(t => t.id !== tag.id);
},
```